# Improve Accuracy for a Siamese Network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I wrote this little model using Keras Functional API to find similarity of a dialogue between two individuals. I am using Gensim's Doc2Vec embeddings for transforming text-data into vectors (vocab size: 4117). My data is equally divided up into 56 positive cases and 64 negative cases. (yes I know the dataset is small - but that's all I have for the time being).

```
def euclidean_distance(vects):
    x, y = vects
    sum_square = K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return K.sqrt(K.maximum(sum_square, K.epsilon()))

ch_inp = Input(shape=(38, 200))
csr_inp = Input(shape=(38, 200))

inp = Input(shape=(38, 200))
net = Embedding(int(vocab_size), 16)(inp)
net = Conv2D(16, 1, activation='relu')(net)
net = TimeDistributed(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))(net)
out = Activation('relu')(net)

sia = Model(inp, out)

x = sia(csr_inp)
y = sia(ch_inp)

sub = Subtract()([x, y])
mul = Multiply()([sub, sub])

mul_x = Multiply()([x, x])
mul_y = Multiply()([y, y])
sub_xy = Subtract()([x, y])

euc = Lambda(euclidean_distance)([x, y])
z = Concatenate(axis=-1)([euc, sub_xy, mul])
z = TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(LSTM(4)))(z)
z = Activation('relu')(z)
z = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(z)
z = Dense(2, activation='relu')(z)
out = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(z)

model = Model([ch_inp, csr_inp], out)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

The problem is: my accuracy won't improve from 60.87% - I ran 10 epochs and the accuracy remains constant. Is there something I've done here in my code that's causing that? Or perhaps its an issue with my data?

[image: View Training Accuracy And Loss here]

I also did K-Fold Validation for some Sklearn models and got these results from the dataset:

[image: Statistical Models Results]

Additionally, an overview of my dataset is attached below:

[image: Dataframe Snapshot]

I'm definitely struggling with this one - so literally any help here would be appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I increased my data-size to 1875 train-samples. Its accuracy improved to 70.28%. But its still constant over all iterations.

Comment: For anyone struggling with this problem in the future, I posted this problem here too: (Incase no one answers on stackoverflow)
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/_uwgRTQUKbU

Comment: Hi, I suggest you learn more basics, specifically what overfitting, training and validation sets are, and only then try to read about the modern techniques how to apply machine learning methods for NLP problems with very small number of training examples.

Comment: umm that's not really helpful. I did try statistical models for the same dataset linked above, but they proved to have smaller accuracies too. I increased my data-size to 1875 samples, which increased the Keras Model accuracy to 70.28%, but its still almost constant. If you have suggestions for which type of model i shud test out or changes in the current model, then do share.

Comment: The problem is that this kind of question is off-topic in SO, its not a programming problem, its a research problem, so its unlikely you will get a useful answer here.

Comment: Maybe your model is too simple for this task?

Comment: @DanielMöller yes I did increase my LSTM units to 16 - but same result. There was another comment in the Keras Google Group where they said that my model is fine - but looks like it might be over-fitting. But I still dont have a definitive answer as to why its acting this way. When I do find out, I'll update here. Meanwhile, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that may be important there.

- You're using `'relu'` after the `LSTM`. An `LSTM` in Keras already has `'tanh'` as default activation. So, although you're not locking your model, you're making it harder for it to learn, with an activation that constraints the results between as small range plus one that cuts the negative values
- You're using `'relu'` with **very few** units! Relu with few units, bad initialization, big learning rates and bad luck will get stuck in the zero region without any gradients.

If your loss completely freezes, it's most probably due to the second point above. And even if it doesn't freeze, it may be using just one unit from the 2 Dense units, for instance, making the layer very poor.

You should do something from below:

- Your model is small, so quit using `'relu'` and use `'tanh'` instead. This will give your model the expected power it should have.
- Otherwise, you should definitely increase the number of units, both for the `LSTM` and for the `Dense`, so `'relu'` doesn't get easily stuck.
- You can add a `BatchNormalization` layer **after `Dense` and before `'relu'`**, this way you guarantee that a good amount units will always be above zero.

In any case, don't use `'relu'` after the `LSTM`.

---

The other approach would be making the model more powerful.

For instance:

```
z = TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(LSTM(4)))(z)
z = Conv1D(10, 3, activation = 'tanh')(z) #or 'relu' maybe
z = MaxPooling1D(z)
z = Conv1D(15, 3, activation = 'tanh')(z) #or 'relu' maybe
z = Flatten()(z) #unless the length is variable, then GlobalAveragePooling1D()(z)
z = Dense(10, activation='relu')(z)
out = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(z)
```

Comment: I changed it to: 
`net = TimeDistributed(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))(net) net = BatchNormalization()(net)
out = Activation('tanh')(net)`
But the accuracy remains the same! :(

Comment: The problem is not only the LSTM, take a look at the entire model.

Comment: Don't add an activation after the LSTM, it already has one, it's standard.

Comment: removed activation layer - i was originally following this [article](https://medium.com/@prabhnoor0212/siamese-network-keras-31a3a8f37d04) and they used a Relu Activation Layer, but even after removing it - do you think maybe a TimeDistributedLSTM is causing this? `net = TimeDistributed(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))(net) out = BatchNormalization()(net)`

Comment: To be honest I don't know. Those would be my first attempts, but I would also try to make the model bigger. See example in the question.